# Service Layer Dependencies: which is the proper way to inject one and the same interface into different services? C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service

I want to understand which is the proper way of implementing the structure of service and its dependencies.

```
public class UpdatesService : IUpdatesService
{
  private readonly IAUpdatesService _aUpdatesService;
  private readonly IInfoService _infoService;

   public UpdatesService (IAUpdatesService aUpdatesService, IInfoService infoService)
    {
        _aUpdatesService = aUpdatesService;
        _infoService = infoService;
    }
}
```

Inside AUpdatesService I have also injection of IInfoService as I am using there business logic related only to that service. Is it mistake to have two injected IInfoService inside the constructor of those services as the IAUpdatesService is adding one more layer of logic to the UpdatesService. Shell I extract the logic inside the upper layer UpdatesService just in order not to inject again the same service IInfoService and pass the result as parameter to the method that is invoking on IAUpdatesService?

```
public class AUpdatesService : IAUpdatesService
{
     private readonly IInfoService _infoService;

     public AUpdatesService(IInfoService infoService)
    {
        _infoService = infoService;;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here. And if IInfoService is a singleton even less so. That IAUpdatesService also needs a IInfoService should be of no concern to UpdatesService its an interna of the other service. And when the implementation changes in the future and then maybe  AUpdatesService no longer needs an IInfoService it should have no influence on UpdatesService.